# how to assign variable value as variable name in a hash?

Tags: javascript, variables

I need to define a hash for posting some ajax data using jQuery.
The hash will look something like:

```
var setname = 'set_1';
elements = { set_1: {'beer','water','wine'} };
```

The challenge I need to solve is 'set-1' (the key of Array elements) should be dynamically named based on the value of `var setname`.

I want to avoid using `eval()` of course..
in PHP it can be done using the double dollar sign like this: `$$setname`, but what's the way to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do what you'd like to like so:

```
var setname = 'set_1', elements = {};
elements[setname] = ['beer','water','wine'];
alert(elements['set_1']); // beer,water,wine
```

See this in action at http://jsfiddle.net/x5KRD/.

All objects in JS can be accessed using *dot notation* (`obj.method()` or `obj.property`), or *bracket notation* (`obj['method']()` or `obj['property']`). Using bracket notation lets you dynamically specify method/property/key names.

For example, while clumsy, `window['alert']('hi')` is equivalent to `window.alert('hi')`.

Note that your code won't work as-is, anyways, because you're using object literal notation (`{'beer','water','wine'}`) to contain an array (it should be in square brackets `['beer','water','wine']` instead). Object literals need to have key-value pairs.

Comment: you're right.. my error, that was an edited simplified version, I actually have key value pairs in my actual object literal. so it works fine except for the dynamic assignment of the key name..

Comment: and I need to do this using a notaion that jQuery.post() will accepts for posting POST data..

Comment: @mikkelbreum I clarified what I was talking about.

Comment: thanks.. and I added that my code example had an error.. my actual code is: elements = { set_1: {drink1: 'beer', drink2: 'water', drink3: 'wine'} };  I need to do this using a notaion that jQuery.post() will accepts for posting POST data.. can I still use the notation elements[setname] = {drink1: 'beer', drink2: 'water', drink3: 'wine'} ? I'll try it, but I somehow feel it wont work..

Comment: @mikkelbreum - no you cannot do that with a simple expression. However, jQuery will accept the "data" value as an arbitrary object - it does not have to be in any "notation".

Comment: Wow it did indeed work, mixing brackets and curlies.. thanks!

Comment: Now I'm posting data = elements[setname] = {drink1: 'beer', drink2: 'water', drink3: 'wine'} and the PHP script receives it as a perfect multidimensional array structured like I want it.

Comment: Well @mikkelbreum I fear that you're not getting the whole "elements" structure, but just that one portion of it.

Comment: Thanks, I know, I just need that specific part of the elements array in this case :)

Comment: It's a real shame we can't use object literal notation, then we could just   return {
    data[0]: { 
      data[1]: data[2]
    }
  }; from a function rather than faffing around creating two objects then assigning the inner one to the outer. Seems inelegant. C'est la vie.

Answer (score 6):

```
var setname = 'set_1', 
    elements = {};

elements[setname] = ['beer','water','wine'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand that there's really no such thing as "JSON notation" in Javascript - it's native Javascript notation that we're talking about. What jQuery wants is a Javascript value for the POST data, not necessarily a Javascript object constant.

Thus, your code will prepare your POST data like this:

```
var elements = {};
elements[setName] = { /* something */ };
elements[somethingElse] = { /* something else */ };
```

and so on. When you're ready to do the POST, you'd just use "elements":

```
$.post(url, elements, function() { /* callback code */ });
```

Answer (score 2):

Directly use [the identifier in square brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names):

```js
const setname = 'set_1';
const elements = { [setname]: ['beer','water','wine'] }
```

Please bear in mind the usage of square brackets for lists