# How to append new elements to the same key in a hash

Tags: javascript, html

I am kind of very new to javascript world. I have a doubt. How do i add/append new values to existing hash. example

```
var setname = 'set_1', elements = {};
elements[setname] = ['beer','water','wine'];
alert(elements['set_1']);
```

Now how do i dynamically add more elements to set_1 key? like to extend the set_1 with coffee tea.

Sorry if this question has been repeated and is very trivial, i did my search. I found one article realted to it,[how to assign variable value as variable name in a hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199126/how-to-assign-variable-value-as-variable-name-in-a-hash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, `elements['set_1']` is just a normal Javascript [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). The fact that it is a property of the `elements` object is completely immaterial to how it behaves.  You can add items to it in the normal Javascript way: with [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
elements['set_1'].push('coffee');
elements['set_1'].push('tea');
```

If you don't know what the property's name will be when you write your code, you can do exactly the same with a variable:

```
elements[setname].push('coffee');
elements[setname].push('tea');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help!

Answer (score 3):

```
elements['set_1'].push('foo');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

If the value of set_1 is an `array` you can do this:

```
var setname = 'set_1', elements = {};
elements[setname] = ['beer','water','wine'];
elements[setname].push('new item');
alert(elements['set_1']);
```

However, if it is not an array, you will need to take different action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help!