# How to rewrite hash assignement in more elegant way

Tags: javascript, hash, coding-style, naming

In my code I use

```
callMethodWithHash({ 'key': "value" });
```

Things work fine until 'key' assigned to another variable (keyHolder). In that case obvious solution:

```
var keyHolder = 'key';
callMethodWithHash(keyHolder: "value");
```

doesn't work ([how to assign variable value as variable name in a hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199126/how-to-assign-variable-value-as-variable-name-in-a-hash)) and I need to write a few more lines:

```
var keyHolder = 'key';
var hash = {};
hash[keyHolder] = "value";
callMethodWithHash(hash);
```

I'm learning JS and would like to develop a good style, but feel like these 3 lines are unnecessary long.

Is there more efficient way to create and pass hash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var keyHolder = "key",
    hash = { [keyHolder]: "value" };

console.log(hash);
```

Keep in mind, that this became available only from [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). You can always see its compatibility [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). In this particular case you should look the **computed property name** feature, it is in **object literal extensions** section, called: **computed properties**.

Comment: You should point out that this uses an ES6 feature. It won't work everywhere out of the box.

Comment: Just did it a few second before. Thanks.

Comment: Can you link a compatibility table? somebody who is just learning JS may not know which ES6 features work where (I know I don't know all of them).